# Tmux window switch and SSH - reattach display

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, tmux

I am attaching through `ssh -Y` to my server, and rotating with tmux to a preexisting window. The problem is, if I just

```
export DISPLAY=:<port ssh used originally for X>
evince #for example
```

On the original (new) window the X forwarding worked fine. I check the port with `echo $DISPLAY` and use that in the above example. When I do this I get:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Is this something I can workaround?

I am on Debian 9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both the correct value for `DISPLAY` and the correct content in `$XAUTHORITY`. `$XAUTHORITY` is usually `~/.Xauthority` and `sshd` will add the authentication secret.

In your error message it seems that `DISPLAY` is not set and that the connection is refused, not denied because of missing authorization.

Comment: Did not even think about that - the new windows do not even define XAUTHORITY, but the old ones did! Can you elaborate on what though of stuff defines it in the environment?

Comment: By the way - the fix was just unsetting the variable in the preexisting window I was trying to hijack, if you want to add that to the answer.